# Is it not OK to ask a Salesforce development question Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions

I posted a Salesforce development question on Stack Overflow:

[Test.loadData with Custom sObject Throws Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511866/test-loaddata-with-custom-sobject-throws-exception)

I immediately got a downvote. I believe I wrote a good question. I properly tagged it.

I also noticed that a similar question never got answered on the Salesforce StackExchange site. My experience with the Salesforce StackExchange site is that Salesforce development questions get downvoted, so I thought posting my Salesforce development question on Stackoverflow was the appropriate move.

Should my question not have been posted on Stack Overflow? I cannot post it on Salesforce StackExchange because it will receive downvotes as it is similar to the other.

Comment: Looks like code to me. A pretty good debugging question at first glance. Not sure why you got a downvote.

Comment: Swisher, regarding your edit: The name of the site is "Stack Overflow" (with a space) and the network is "Stack Exchange" (also with a space). That is why your post was edited by ProgramFOX in the first place, though they did miss one and made a small typo themselves.

Comment: @Kendra The actual name of the site can be confusing to new users, especially when the site often switches between formats(with/without a space). The title image on every page doesn't have a space.

Comment: @Grice I know this. The image tries to portray the space through different font weights, which is how a lot of images do similar things, from my experience. Stack Overflow itself does _not_ switch between formats, users misconstrue the name as "StackOverflow" and other users assume this is true. To quote the [legal/trademark page:](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) _"As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters)."_ (See the "Proper Use" section at the bottom.)  I was teaching a new user this, so why did you need to point this out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, it's fine to ask them.

You *might* have been down voted because one of the first results when googling "System.StringException: Unknown field: Territory__c salesforce" happens to be:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50146/can-we-load-test-data-thorugh-csv-using-test-loaddata-for-custom-objects

(With the precise same error message, and a good potential reason. Not saying you *should* mention that specific related question in your own, or other related questions you may have found. But something as simple as "I couldn't find any reason that applied to me when googling this error message" can make a world of difference when it comes to debugging.)